# Maximum voltage on metal sphere?

Tags: electrostatics, condensed-matter, atomic-physics

What is the maximum voltage that can be put on a metal sphere before electrons fly off it or the metal itself explodes due to electrostatic forces?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What limits the maximum sustainable surface charge density of a sphere in space?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62416/)

Comment: John, the question I've linked asks about the maximum charge but this is related to the voltage by $Q = CV$ where $C$ is the capacitance of the sphere $C = 4\pi\epsilon_0R$. So it is an answer to your question as well.

Comment: If you are interested in the answer for a sphere in vacuum, I agree that John's duplicate is valid. But otherwise, there are many other things to consider (specifically, the dielectric strength of the medium surrounding the sphere). The duplicate also doesn't address the force on the sphere - most "metal" spheres are unlikely to be ripped apart by electrostatic force (although it depends on dimensions), but soap bubbles could be. So - do you feel your question has been answered, or do you want these issues to be addressed more fully?